# Validation on login form

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ardent

Here is my postLogin method:

```
$userdata = array(
        'email'     => Input::get('email'),
        'password'  => Input::get('password'),
        'enabled'   => 1
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($userdata))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }

    return Redirect::route('login')
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
        ->withErrors(array('password' => 'Password invalid'));
```

I use Ardent in my Model. How do I validate the login form and get the error messages since I'm not using Ardent->save()?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
$input = Input::all();
$rules = array('email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required');

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('login')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
} else {

    $userdata = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password'),
            'enabled'   => 1
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
        $remember = Input::get('remember');
        if(!empty($remember)) {
            Auth::login(Auth::user(), true);
        }
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('login')
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
        ->withErrors(array('password' => 'Password invalid'));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm already using Ardent in the model so I don't have to do validation in the controller. Does anyone know a way to validate against that?